# in centos R can't find make

Tags: r, gcc, centos

I have R on centos machine. It normally comes with gcc 4.8 but at least one package (lubridate) needs a newer version. So I have updated the gcc. `which gcc` returns `/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc`

`which g++` returns `/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/g++`
`gcc --version` returns `gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)`
and

`echo $PATH` returns `/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/gnelson/bin`

So it appears I have a new version of gcc and g++ and the path to them is included in my PATH

But when I run R in a terminal and try to run `install.packages("lubridate")`, I have problems. It wants to first install Rcpp but when it tries to do that I get the following error.

```
g++7.3.1 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
/bin/sh: g++7.3.1: command not found
make: *** [Date.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
```

Lubridate also fails to install. What do I need to change?

More issues. I login into Rstudio on centos server. I run `.libPaths()` in the console. It returns

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/gerald/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5" "/usr/lib64/R/library"                              
[3] "/usr/share/R/library"
```

Then I run it in the terminal window that Rstudio makes available and get

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/gerald/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4"
[2] "/usr/lib64/R/library"
[3] "/usr/share/R/library"
```

`install.packages("lubridate")` compiles successfully in the terminal but not in the Rstudio console.

At the moment, I'm lost in linux land.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `-` in between `g++` and `7.3.1`? That is, changing (e.g.) `CXX1X=g++7.3.1` to `CXX1X=g++-7.3.1` in your `~/.R/Makevars`?

Comment: Here's what my Makevars file looks like`CC=gcc-7.3.1
CXX=g++7.3.1
CXX_STD=CXX
CXX1X=g++-7.3.1
SHLIB_CXXLD=g++7.3.1` so the `-` is there already. Do the other lines also need a `-`; eg `CXX=g++-7.3.1`

Comment: I would try it. I might also note that I'm not 100% sure whether you need the `.1` in `7.3.1`.

Comment: I had the same issue recently. Can you please elaborate more on "install.packages("lubridate") compiles successfully in the terminal but not in the Rstudio console." ?

Comment: This is not specific to centos but applies to (at least) the Mac OS and ubuntu. 1. launch a terminal window. 2. Type "R". If R is installed, copy "install.packages("lubridate")" (without the outside quotes to the terminal prompt. If R is installed this will install lubridate. It will then also be available in RStudio.

Comment: Basically this process gives you access to the terminal PATH which can be different than the PATH that RStudio uses.